# What was the 3D file browser used in Jurassic Park?

Tags: file-management

What was the 3D file browser used in the movie "Jurassic Park"?

Is it a real product and is it still relevant today?

Comment: ah ah ah, you didn't say the magic word.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

3D file browser was FSN on IRIX, there are similar opensource browser http://fsv.sourceforge.net/ .

It's really just for looking cool, not very useful.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it was the [File System Navigator in IRIX](http://www.siliconbunny.com/fsn-the-irix-3d-file-system-tool-from-jurassic-park/).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question - it's no longer relevant.

3D file systems are really just a gimmick. They don't add anything to the user experience & usually get in the way.

Comment: … like OS themes and 3D videos and VR…